# How to add CardSpace support to your ASP.NET application

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, cardspace

I like the idea of CardSpace but unlike OpenID it seems like a real PITA
to support it in your ASP.NET web application. I've found many examples, even a tutorial
in one of the books I own... but it would seem a lot more is required than what they suggest.

Changes to the server and such?

Can someone tell me:

- What I need to configure in IIS7
- How to implement CardSpace support without using to many 3rd party components
- Have you managed to get it working?

I think the complexity (or poor documentation) is one of the reasons CardSpace is lagging behind.

(I'm interested in what others think about this, but lets not turn this into a flame war, I just want a solution and perhaps your thoughs in short)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have blogged about that, but it is in Swedish. I hope we can rely on google translate. :-)

[Get Started](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fweblogs.asp.net%2Fmikaelsoderstrom%2Farchive%2F2008%2F09%2F08%2Fwindows-cardspace-kom-ig-229-ng.aspx&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&sl=sv&tl=en)

[Use Windows CardSpace with ASP.NET Membership](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fweblogs.asp.net%2Fmikaelsoderstrom%2Farchive%2F2008%2F09%2F09%2Fkoppla-ihop-windows-cardspace-med-asp-net-membership.aspx&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=sv&tl=en)

[Get an InfoCard with Javascript](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fweblogs.asp.net%2Fmikaelsoderstrom%2Farchive%2F2008%2F10%2F02%2Fh-228-mta-ett-infocard-med-javascript.aspx&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=sv&tl=en)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For card space take a look at the open source library SharpSTS a https://sharpsts.com/

They also have links to a number of card space resources that might help you get started at: https://sharpsts.com/resources.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Rob Conery is implementing CardSpace in his new project.
http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvcstore-part-17/

Hope it helps